# Boolean operations on generic polyhedrons (including non-regular) with blind holes

Tags: boolean-algebra, computational-geometry, polyhedra

Is any one aware of the geometric algorithm to compute Boolean operations on generic (concave also) polyhedrons ( STLs: Bounded by triangular patches for a simple case) with blind holes ) in 3D and for that matter in any dimensions more than 3D(n-D)?

The algorithm should not be iterative and should not fall into the category of Randomized algorithms, by which I mean, it should be just direct. Please let me know.